# Package not available after successfully installed with apt-get or pip

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, upgrade, python

I'm trying to install some libraries on my Ubuntu machines. Take this library as an example - virtualenv

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-172:~$ sudo apt install virtualenv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
virtualenv is already the newest version (15.0.1+ds-3ubuntu1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm4.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-172:~$
```

But now when i try to use virtualenv i get -

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-172:~$ virtualenv
The program 'virtualenv' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install virtualenv
```

Same for 'pip3' library

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-172:~$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm4.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-172:~$

ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-172:~$ pip3
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Your $PATH value was modified incorrectly?  `pip3` is installed in /usr/bin/ on my system, is yours there? and does that directory exist in your $PATH?

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-172:~$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/ubuntu/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7//bin:/home/ubuntu/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7//bin:/home/ubuntu/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7//bin

Comment: I couldn't find pip3 inside /usr/bin/

Comment: `dpkg -L virtualenv` will show you all the files installed by the package.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by uninstalling and reinstalling all the above libraries

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualenv
sudo apt-get purge python3-pip
```

and then I reinstalled these again. The issue I think could be - I changed from my default python version from 2.7 to 3.5.